# Is it possible to prevent `pipenv` from hardcoding absolute interpreter paths into files?

Tags: python, pipenv

Consider the following `Pipefile`:

```
[[source]]
name = "pypi"
url = "https://pypi.org/simple"
verify_ssl = true

[dev-packages]
mysqlclient         = "==1.4.*"

[requires]
python_version      = "3.7"
```

I run the following commands in the directory `/Users/hqin/tmp/PipPlay`.

```
pipenv lock
PIPENV_VENV_IN_PROJECT=true pipenv sync
```

Then I open the file `.venv/bin/pip` and find the following line at the top:

```
#!/Users/hqin/tmp/PipPlay/.venv/bin/python3.7
```

Observe that the absolute path of the current directory is hardcoded into the file.

Is there some flag I can pass to `pipenv` or environmental variable I can set to avoid this hardcoding and instead either use a relative path or no interpreter line?

Answer (score 0):

If you are sure you will only run script from root directory (in your case `/Users/hqin/tmp/PipPlay/`) you can use the following shebang. (I am not sure it is best practice or not but it works for us).

```
#!.venv/bin/python3.7
```